# How can I get my grass object to deform with hair particle system on a weight painted plane?

Tags: particles, hair, instances, surface-deform

I was trying to create a cartoonish looking plane. And, this is what I have come up with as of now:

[image]

The problem here is that the grass object, that has the following modifier on it:

[image]

and the following geometry made purely from loop cutting a cylinder and scaling edge loops, I haven't even merged the vertices on the top.

[image]

Its origin is at the 3d cursor position.

A particle system modifier is on the plane with a density weight painted vertex group

[image]

But the resultant grass is first misplaced, and second it is deformed in a very weird way far from original shape.

How can I get it to work properly

My blend file is available at the following link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UPhBYJYL0zZ49tzun79Zpjkeh4lekMxG/view?usp=sharing

Before this gets marked as duplicate, I must tell you I have been at this for a few hours now, and I have tried several different solutions. I am not a expert blender user, just a casual user so don't expect me to understand high level modifiers.

Comment: select your grass strand - hit alt-g -> is that what you want?

Comment: As Chris says, move the herb object at the same location as your ground object, that's how the Particle Instance modifier is supposed to work